# Present a view controller on different UIWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

I need help solving this problem I've been having for two whole days. Let say I had a custom view controller that handles image slideshows and it can be used to embed on a view or present it via navigation controller or as modal view. It also has full screen options which can be turned on using this code

> ```
>         _fullScreenWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
>         _fullScreenWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
>         _fullScreenWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;             
>         _fullScreenWindow.rootViewController = self;            
>         [_fullScreenWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
> ```

I stored the original window beforehand so I can restore its state when exiting full screen. This also calls the orientation methods, which is not called when its in navigation controller. So while in full screen mode state, there is a option which can be presented as a uitableviewcontroller so in theory I can present it using this code.

> ```
>     UITableViewController *mediaOptionsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
>     UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mediaOptionsController];
>     [navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
>     navController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = dismissButton;
>     //mainViewController is the custom view controller, which is on different uiwindow
>     [mainViewController  presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
> ```

But I got this warning whenever I use this option and thus unable to present it

> Warning: Attempt to present UINavigationController on UINavigationController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Any idea why its not working? Just so you know setting the root controller on the app delegate is not viable since I went directly to the root controller's view instead of the current top view of the navigation controller

Comment: Why you want to use two `UIWindows`?

Comment: The error indicates that `mainViewController` has not been added to either window. Is this true?

Comment: @Anil, I did consider using the app delegate's window but if I had a root controller that navigates to point A->B->…Z where Z uses the custom controller but when I exit full screen it goes to root controller instead of going back to Z, hence the 2 UIWIndows.

Comment: @maddy, the mainViewController is the rootviewcontroller on the 2nd uiwindow, which is also the custom view controller. I assume that it should be on the view since its showing on my side but thats not the case on the program.

Comment: There also i dont think you need 2 windows. you can just do `self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController` or any other controller you want to make as root view controller

Comment: @Anil, like I said, using 1 window will return me to the root controller when I exit full screen instead of the top view controller that is pushed in the root's navigation controller or its presented. Ie setting self.window.rootViewController = _originalRootController is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution but I resolved this issue by dismissing the 2nd window and make the main  window key, and then present the options from there. Only by exiting the options will I make the 2nd window key again.

Comment: There is no reason to use two windows in this situation. You need to fix your problem with the navigation controller

Comment: @Lance maybe its better to provide a solution for this. Believe me I already tried 1 window and it didn't work when restoring the original root controller